# Change a URL in wordpress for SEO

Tags: wordpress, custom-url

I am using a custom plugin, which searches data and displays it

For eg, If i am displaying cars with manufacturer hyundai, it shows

http://www.mybaseurl.com/inventory/?car_manufacturer=hyundai

I want to change this URL to

http://www.mybaseurl.com/inventory/hyundai

This is not a page/post, its something the plugin generates.

Is there a plugin that can help me mask the URL to what i want?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use this plugin for that: [Redirection plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/)